# Server Error (500) when starting my dockerized laravel app

Tags: docker, laravel-5, php-7.4

I have created a laravel app and then created a `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM php:7.4-cli

RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y libmcrypt-dev

RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo 
#mbstring

WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app

RUN composer install

EXPOSE 8000
CMD php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0 --port=8000
```

Then I ran `sudo docker build -t myApp .` and  `sudo docker run -it -p 8000:8000 news-organizer`. Everything worked fine.

When I copy this folder (with Dockerfile) to another location and run `composer update --ignore-platform-reqs`, `sudo docker build --no-cache -t theApp .` and `sudo docker run -it -p 8888:8888 theApp` the Web App starts. When I enter `127.0.0.1:8888` I get the *500 Error*.

I already set all rights to `sudo chmod 755 -R <myLaravelFolder>`. I also tried setting different port numbers. The `Dockerfile` of the new folder is:

```
FROM php:7.4-cli

RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y libmcrypt-dev

RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo 
#mbstring

WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app

RUN composer install

EXPOSE 8888
CMD php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0 --port=8888
```

I just can't find a way to fix the 500 Error. What can I do?

**My basic idea is**: Creating a Laravel Web-App. Then creating a Dockerfile and upload it somewhere. Then others can download the Web App, install Docker, and run `sudo docker build -t <myImage> .` and `sudo docker run -it -p 8000:8000 <myImage>`. With that they can use my Laravel App on their computers as docker container.

I run xubuntu 20.04 as OS.

Comment: Key point: *YOU NEED TO CHECK THE SERVER LOGS*! The only way to "fix the 500 error" is to learn exactly where/why the server is failing.  Please "Edit" your post and copy/paste the server-side error message you find.

Comment: Furthermore, you shouldn't be using sudo privileges when invoking docker. The official docs teach you how to create the docker group.

Comment: 500 error means something is wrong with your app. You should add some logging and inspect the logfiles

Answer (score -1):

Thank you for hinting at the logs. Eventually, I found that I had to **generate the application key**. It can be done via `php artisan key:generate`.

Comment: Please "Edit" your post and copy/paste the log message that told you this.  This "solution" is pretty much useless without being able to search on the error message :(